# UnmodifiableMap with Function<X, Y> values fails to compile

Tags: java, function, collections, unmodifiable

I have a reference:

```
public final static LinkedHashMap<String, Function<OrderBean, String>> DELEGATES;
```

Which I initialize like:

```
static {
    LinkedHashMap<String, Function<OrderBean, String>> tmp = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    tmp.put(OrderCols.FIELD1, OrderBean::getFIELD1);
    tmp.put(OrderCols.FIELD2, OrderBean::getFIELD2);
    ...        
    DELEGATES = Collections.unmodifiableMap(tmp);
}
```

On the last line of the static block (the assignment to DELEGATES), I get this compiler error:

Error:(64, 48) java: incompatible types: no instance(s) of type variable(s) K,V exist so that java.util.Map conforms to java.util.LinkedHashMap>

Am I messing something up? Or do unmodifiable views don't like Function types?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, your issue is that instead of

```
public final static LinkedHashMap<String, Function<OrderBean, String>> DELEGATES;
```

you should have

```
public final static Map<String, Function<OrderBean, String>> DELEGATES;
```

...because `unmodifiableMap` returns a bare `Map` implementation.  (The backing data structure will still be a `LinkedHashMap`, though.)

Comment: Well that was pretty fast

Comment: I want to force the external one to be a LinkedHashMap. Can I just cast it? It seems to be fine with the compiler.

Comment: @DiegoMartinoia: Nope, you can't do that; it'll break with a `ClassCastException` at runtime.  You _have_ to do it like this.

Comment: Louis is blazing fast and on point, casting and double casting throw CCExceptions. @Louis, is there any way to compile-time type the DELEGATES as a linkedhashmap? Otherwise I'll be happy to avoid that :)

Comment: When I said you have to do it like this, I meant _you have to do it like this._  No, you can't make it a `LinkedHashMap`.

Comment: OK, sorry for asking if there was any other way :( Thanks for the quick and valid reply!